# ConEmu + bash CTRL+L no longer working

Tags: bash, cygwin, conemu

I set up the following task in ConEmu in order to run bash:

```
C:\cygwin\bin\bash.exe --login -i  -cur_console:d:C:\cygwin\bin
```

Up until today, it ran wonderfully. However, I updated cygwin today, and now <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd> doesn't work (it seems to work like <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>, or just <kbd>Enter</kbd> -- another line is entered). Mintty works as expected (<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd> works fine).

Any ideas on what is going on here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Upd**. That was the change of cygwin's clear screen realization. ConEmu had blocked some activities with console screen buffer. Corrected in the build **140416**.

*The rest of answer left for the history, because it still may be actual for other cugwin problems.*

To ensure that is cygwin problem - run from Win+R (not from mintty) your shell

```
C:\cygwin\bin\bash.exe --login -i
```

And try your action (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>L</kbd>). If it reproduced in the standard console - report bugs to cygwin team.

Comment: I ran bash, and it cleared normally (Ctrl+L). But a reboot fixed it. Sorry about that...

Comment: Answer updated. Build 1400416.

Comment: Thank you. I _just_ had this problem recur, and I came back here to add a comment, and you'd noted that a new release fixed the problem 4 minutes before I came here. Thank you so much!